# Shape works fine Android 2.x.x but different Android 4.x.x

Tags: android, shapes

I'm trying to create slide button with ring shape

rounded_cell.xml in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="2"
android:useLevel="false" >

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<size
    android:height="15dp"
    android:width="15dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/l_blue" />

</shape>
```

Comment: change android:shape="oval" like mention under.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Make an button.xml in ur "drawable folder".

Step 2: Add under mention code.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="#FFF" />
<stroke android:width="1sp"
    android:color="#FF0000"/>
```

Step 3: Apply it to button

Comment: I tried your code but result is same. Android 2.3.3 is works fine. But the result of Android 4.2.2 is much bigger circles are there. How can i solve?

Comment: copy and paste this xml file in all the drawable folders(i.e. drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi), it is working fine with my application

Comment: I cant resolve this problem, here is the results https://www.dropbox.com/s/dkncrr1a8taqtft/image.PNG First one is android 2.3.3 and Second one is android 4.2.2